# References about Nomizu Conjecture

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

tI want to look for some references about Nomizu Conjecture(if $R(X,Y)R = 0$ Then $\nabla R = 0$),is there anyone know some papers/references about Nomizu Conjecture or the progress about Nomizu Conjecture.

Answer (score 8):

Luis A. Florit, Wolfgang Ziller, [Manifolds with conullity at most two as graph manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06572)

Abstract states: "... [W]e show that Nomizu's conjecture, well known to be false in general, is true for manifolds with finite volume."